# Is there a 404 errorcode fallback page for svelte-routing?

Tags: http-status-code-404, svelte

This fallback component={NotFound} is the only way i found for error pages but returns a component page with server code 200, i'd like to get code 404.

Is there a way **Not** using sveltekit ?

```
import { Router, Link, Route } from "svelte-routing";
import NotFound from "./components/NotFound.svelte";
...
            <Route path="/">
                Welcome <hr />
                <Login {toast}/>
            </Route>
            <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Router>
```

Answer (score 2):

`svelte-routing` is a component-based router and as such it has no control over your server, so it can't manipulate the response in any way other than picking the right component for you. You can still return different status codes, but you need to do it manually server-side.

If you're using static file hosting, I don't think there's a way to do it other than listing all your valid routes in your platform's configuration so that it can return 200 on valid routes and 404 otherwise. The route duplication is unfortunate but it's likely unavoidable.

However, if you're server-side rendering your app, you can communicate with your components in order to respond with the right status code. In your request handler, create a context object to hold your data:

```js
import App from './App.svelte';
import { generatePage } from './page-template.js';

function handler(request, response) {
  const SSR_RESPONSE = { statusCode: 200 };

  const renderedApp = App.render(
    { url: req.url },
    { context: new Map([['SSR_RESPONSE', SSR_RESPONSE]]) }
  );

  response.statusCode = SSR_RESPONSE.statusCode;
  response.end(generatePage(renderedApp));
}
```

You can now read and write to this object from your components:

```html
<!-- NotFound.svelte -->
<script>
  import { getContext } from 'svelte';

  getContext('SSR_RESPONSE').statusCode = 404;
</script>

<h1>Not found</h1>
```

This technique can be used not only for status codes but for headers, conditional templating, or whatever else you can think of.

Note that in order for this to work, you must set your context values during component initialization (ie. not in callbacks, in asynchronous contexts, `setTimeout`s, etc). This is required because SSR happens *synchronously*, so by the time you update the context asynchronously, your response will have already been sent.

Comment: havent worked with ssr yet...
could i just plug this into my project? i dont mind for a bit of the just barely node stuff. but rather static if i understood it would be impossible or have to set it in smth like a .htaccess...
in which file would the first codes go? a main.js or server.js imported from that?
else, i'd appreciate some docs links. cant find in this how to https://svelte.dev/docs

Comment: https://github.com/b2io/svelte-ssr-demo/blob/main/1-basic-ssr/scripts/ssr-server.js

Comment: Static files would make this harder to do, yes, but it'd still be possible. Is your project currently being served as static files? What kind of hosting do you use?

There isn't a full server included in this example, it rather illustrates what you'd need to do in case you had one already. It'd be hard to explain how to manually set up an express/polka server with all the bundler setup necessary here, so if you'd move to SSR for this, I must ask: why _not_ SvelteKit?

Comment: Regarding the Svelte docs, the only thing you'll find there is the Server-side Component API. Since Svelte is just a component framework, it doesn't deal with setting up a server for you—you call into the Component API from a normal Node HTTP server instead.